# POST Json to MVC Controller - No action was found on controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've got the following AJAX request:

```
var recordToRevert = $(this);
var umbrellaId = $(this).data("id");
var requestData = {
    umbrellaId: umbrellaId,
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/Express2/api/BenefitBank/RevertTransactionUmbrella",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
    headers: {
        "Authorization-Token": "7,181,22",
        "CentreNumber": "0"
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data.FoundRevertableTransactions) {
        recordToRevert.parent().html("<span class=\"success\">Reverted</span)");
    } else {
        alert('Umbrella NOT reverted');
    }
}).fail(function () {
    alert('Umbrella NOT reverted');
});
```

I'm sending it to an MVC controller/action here:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("RevertTransactionUmbrella")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostRevertTransactionUmbrella(Int64 umbrellaId)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
snip...
```

This is the response that i'm getting.

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/Express2/api/BenefitBank/RevertTransactionUmbrella'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'BenefitBank' that matches the request."}
```

I've set a breakpoint and the controller action is not being hit.  I wonder if i'm not sending the JSON correctly?

This request works though:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Express2/api/BenefitBank/GetRequestObjects",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    //data: JSON.stringify(requestData),

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetRequestObjects")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetRequestObjects()
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new BenefitBankRequestObjects());
}
```

It looks like the controller is being hit on both requests, however, the action is not being hit on the first?

Comment: Try with: `public HttpResponseMessage PostRevertTransactionUmbrella([FromBody]Int64 umbrellaId)`

Comment: ah, i'm hitting the action now, the parameters not being passed through though

Comment: Make sure that your JSON property names matches with casing your action parameters... and you have an extra comma in: `var requestData = {
    umbrellaId: umbrellaId,
};` so it should be `var requestData = {
    umbrellaId: umbrellaId
};`

Comment: It all matches but I'm now getting {"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'umbrellaId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage PostRevertTransactionUmbrella(Int64)' in 'Express.ExpressRESTAPI.Controllers.BenefitBankController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you must pass a query string equivalent to `Int64 umbrellaId` or set its default value to zero.

Comment: Changing the request to GET and sending through the query string did the trick, thanks

Comment: You can also do POST and pass query string in the POST as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try changin the URL from:

```
url: "/Express2/api/BenefitBank/RevertTransactionUmbrella"
```

to:

```
url: "/Express2/api/BenefitBank/PostRevertSingleTransaction"
```

Comment: I had the action name incorrect in the controller (now corrected in the question).  However changing to "/Express2/api/BenefitBank/PostRevertTransactionUmbrella" doesn't work